# Is higher resolution coastline data readily available for R

Tags: r, ggmap

I am hoping to create a map for a relatively small area of the coast (~ 3 degrees in lon and lat extension). Is anyone aware of readily available data for R at a higher resolution than that provided by the high resolution data in the mapdata package? Or is anyone aware of source and method for importing this data?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this, which a found in Google:  http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html

Comment: This will be a good source of the data if nothing else is "R-ready". I imagine there will be some playing around involved to import the polygon shapes into R, however.

Comment: Any data is "R ready". `rgdal` package traverses the bridge between different formats and R.

Comment: Where _any_ is defined as any _spatial_ data :). But I agree with Roman, `rgdal` provides the means of reading just about all spatial data.

Comment: re GSHHG, gbm.basemap from gbm.auto (https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm.auto/index.html) extracts this for your extents (disclaimer: I'm the author), however I'm looking for a higher res option for very high level zoom: https://github.com/SimonDedman/gbm.auto/issues/70

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about mapdata, but google maps and openstreetmaps can give small areas. The `ggmap` package makes the getting and rendering of the maps reasonably straightforward. The code below gives waterways of the Gogodala region in Papua New Guinea's Western Province. Is the resulution high enough?

```
library(ggmap)
pngMAP_df = get_map(location = c(142.5, -8.10, 143.1, -7.9), source = "osm", zoom = 12)
ggmap(pngMAP_df)
```

Comment: This is a nice package - I didn't know about it. I am having difficulty with the source="google" option - it doesn't respect my location limits very well. e.g. pngMAP_df = get_map(location = c(-113, 23, -110, 26), source = "google", zoom = 8); ggmap(pngMAP_df)

Comment: You also don't seem to be able to add other lower level plots to this (e.g. a polygon)

Comment: @Marc in the box: Try a location vector with one lon and one lat; i.e., the center of the map. So, `pngMAP_df = get_map(location = c(lon = -112, lat = 23.5), source = "google", zoom = 8)`, followed by `ggmap(pngMAP_df)` will generate your map. Then adjust the centre to suit. BTW, source = "google"is default.

Comment: @Marc in the box:  ggmap plays well with ggplot2. Any ggplot2 geom can be added to the map. A good resource is available here: [http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24648660/RJwrapper.pdf]

Comment: Thanks Sandy - works great now. Can you check your dropbox link? I'm not able to open it. Is it a public folder?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should read: dl.dropbox.com/u/24648660/RJwrapper.pdf    It's not mine so ...